# SQL How to show "parent" value based on in-table multiple level hierarchy?

Tags: sql

I have a generic query returning item info:

```
SELECT 
    Item.StoreID
    ,Item.ItemID
    ,Item.Name
    ,Item.PricingID
    ,Pricing.Name 
    ,Item.ItemGroupID
FROM 
    Item
JOIN 
    Pricing ON Pricing.PricingID = Item.PricingID
WHERE 
    Item.StoreID = 11
```

I also have a table with information about categories looking like this:

```
[ItemGroupID], [ParentGroupID], [GroupName]
1,null
2,null
3,1
4,3
5,null
```

Which delineates relations of groups with one another - so group [4] is sub group [3], [3] is subgroup of [1] and [1], [2] and [5] are overarching parent categories.

**Question:** how can I make it so first report also shows item's [parent category] based on that group table?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, edit your question, add tag of dbms being used, example output of your current query ans example of expected output for it.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add the extra table (Categories) to your joins:

```
SELECT 
    Item.StoreID
    ,Item.ItemID
    ,Item.Name
    ,Item.PricingID
    ,Pricing.Name 
    ,Item.ItemGroupID
    ,Categories.ParentGroupID
FROM
    Item
    JOIN Pricing 
    ON Pricing.PricingID = Item.PricingID
    INNER JOIN Categories
    ON Item.ItemGroupID = Categories.ItemGroupID
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! But this would show only category directly associated with item, as i understand?
I.e. item has "category ID" 3, so "parent id" needed to be return should be 1

Comment: That is what an inner join accomplishes. Did you try it? Show your data and expected output.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but this still doesn't seem to be what i have in mind - it returns a DIRECT parent category instead of the "overarching" one. Here is example of resulting columns in question:

CategoryGroupID ParentCategoryID

2 NULL

3 NULL

5 4

94 5


- so 94 category links 5th category as its "final" parent and 5th - does so to 4th. While they both should return 4 as their overarching parent.